# Small MCU with two RS-232 ports mounted in a box

Tags: processor, case, rs-232

I need two serial ports (RS-232) and an MCU already mounted in a box.  This is not something that requires an OS, so Arduino level is fine.  It is going to read in serial data on one port (9,600 bps) and spit it out again with a bit of reformatting.  The input data is a 50 character burst every 1 second.

I figure the unit will run from a 5V wall wart.

I've looked at Digikey, Mouser and done numerous web searches.  The closest I could find are not really programmable units, but serial port "servers".

https://www.brainboxes.com/product/ethernet-to-serial/db9/es-257

https://www.brainboxes.com/product/usb-to-serial/usb/us-257

If I could program these, $100 would be the right price.

Answer (score 0):

The brainboxes and other products like these would be perfect for this job, but these companies are not interested in offering the products for sale in this use.  I expect they do not want to have to do the work required to document the interfaces for customer use.

However, I did find what seem to be suitable units, sold for customer programming... but they are higher end devices, intended to run an OS like Windows or Linux.  Still, they will do the job, in theory.  They are from Aaeon.  But they don't have very many in stock and so far, I've not reached them through their "contact us" information.